# How can I see the SQL code Speedment sends to the database?

Tags: speedment

When I create and use a stream with Speedment, how can I see what is sent to the database? For example, if I try the first example on GitHub:

```
Optional<Film> longFilm = films.stream()
    .filter(Film.LENGTH.greaterThan(120))
    .findAny();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the queries generated by attaching a logger to the builder when you first setup the Speedment Application.

```
final DemoApplication app = new DemoApplicationBuilder()
        .withLogging(ApplicationBuilder.LogType.STREAM)
        .build();
```

Now when you invoke .findAny(), the generated SQL query will be shown in the output.